# EXC_BAD_ACCESS, unable to locate the error

Tags: c, exc-bad-access

i have been trying to resolve this issue for quite some time hopefully someone here would be able to explain on how i'd be able to handle this issue.

I've read about it being a pointer pointing to an unallocated set of memory, however i have not yet free'd anything nor am i able to find where i'm lacking.

The error:

```
Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff50fefff8)
```

I've been debugging my error and it returns me to this function:

```
int         check_tetrimino(char **grid, t_tetrimino curr, int ind_y, int ind_x)
{
    int y;
    int x;
    int size;

    size = ft_strlen(grid[0]); // <----- points to this exact line
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    while (x < 4)
    {
        if (ind_y + curr.y[y] >= size)
            return (-1);
        if (grid[ind_y + curr.y[y]][ind_x + curr.x[x]] != '.')
            return (0);
        x++;
        y++;
    }
    //printf("%c fit on y:%d, x:%d.\n", curr.letter, ind_y, ind_x);
    return (add_to_grid(grid, curr, ind_y, ind_x));
}
```

This is the recursive function calling check_tetrimino

```
int         check_all_tetr(char **grid, t_tetrimino *curr, int ind_y, int ind_x)
{
    static int tries = 0;
    int size;
    int check_ret;

    size = ft_strlen(grid[0]);
    check_ret = check_tetrimino(grid, *curr, ind_y, ind_x);
    if (check_ret == 0) {
        (ind_x < (size - 1)) ? ++ind_x : ++ind_y && (ind_x = 0);
    }
    if (check_ret == 1)
    {
        if (!(curr->next->letter > 'A' && curr->next->letter < 'Z'))
            return (1);
        assign_curr(&curr, &ind_y, &ind_x);
    }
    if (check_ret == -1)
    {
        if (curr->prev == NULL)
        {
            delete_from_grid(grid, *curr);
            return (-1);
        }
        curr = curr->prev != NULL ? curr->prev : curr;
        delete_from_grid(grid, *curr);
        return (ind_x < (size - 1) ?
                check_all_tetr(grid, curr, curr->grid_y, curr->grid_x + 1) :
                check_all_tetr(grid, curr, curr->grid_y + 1, 0));
    }
    return (check_all_tetr(grid, curr, ind_y, ind_x));
}
```

this is my ft_strlen:

```
size_t      ft_strlen(const char *s)
{
    size_t index;

    index = 0;
    while (s[index] != '\0')
        index++;
        return (index);
}
```

Grid Generator:

```
/*
** Genererates a 2D Array performing as a grid
** the size of the grid is based on the amount of tetrimino's
** possible minimum required elements is = √ ⋅ 4
** @param size
** @param size_elem
** @return
*/

char        **ft_grid_gen(size_t size)
{
    char    **map;
    int     index;
    int     elem_index;
    int     grid_size;

    index = 0;
    elem_index = 0;
    grid_size = ft_calc_sqrt(size);
    map = malloc((grid_size * sizeof(*map)) + 1);
    map[grid_size] = NULL;
    while (index < grid_size)
    {
        map[index] = malloc(grid_size * sizeof(char) + 1);
        map[index][grid_size] = '\0';
        while (elem_index < grid_size)
        {
            map[index][elem_index] = '.';
            elem_index++;
        }
        index++;
        elem_index = 0;
    }
    return (map);
}
```

the Entire valgrind:

```
==7641== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7641== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7641== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7641== Command: ./fillit valid_19
==7641== 
==7641== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7641==    at 0x100001E2F: ft_strlen (in ./fillit)
==7641==    by 0x10000110D: ft_validator (validator.c:29)
==7641==    by 0x100001339: ft_sort_list (sort_list.c:35)
==7641==    by 0x100000F75: main (main.c:41)
==7641== 
==7641== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7641==    at 0x100001367: ft_sort_list (sort_list.c:37)
==7641==    by 0x100000F75: main (main.c:41)
==7641== 
==7641== Invalid read of size 1
==7641==    at 0x100001E28: ft_strlen (in ./fillit)
==7641==    by 0x10000110D: ft_validator (validator.c:29)
==7641==    by 0x100001339: ft_sort_list (sort_list.c:35)
==7641==    by 0x100000F75: main (main.c:41)
==7641==  Address 0x100b58d95 is 0 bytes after a block of size 21 alloc'd
==7641==    at 0x1000991E6: malloc (in /Users/dvan-boc/.brew/Cellar/valgrind/3.14.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==7641==    by 0x100001070: ft_read (reader.c:43)
==7641==    by 0x100000F63: main (main.c:40)
==7641== 
==7641== Invalid read of size 1
==7641==    at 0x100001360: ft_sort_list (sort_list.c:37)
==7641==    by 0x100000F75: main (main.c:41)
==7641==  Address 0x100b58d95 is 0 bytes after a block of size 21 alloc'd
==7641==    at 0x1000991E6: malloc (in /Users/dvan-boc/.brew/Cellar/valgrind/3.14.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==7641==    by 0x100001070: ft_read (reader.c:43)
==7641==    by 0x100000F63: main (main.c:40)
==7641== 
==7641== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7641==    at 0x100001873: subtract_coordinates (solver.c:171)
==7641==    by 0x1000017C6: ft_solve (solver.c:45)
==7641==    by 0x100000FBA: main (main.c:49)
==7641== 
==7641== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7641==    at 0x100001873: subtract_coordinates (solver.c:171)
==7641==    by 0x100001959: subtract_coordinates (solver.c:190)
==7641==    by 0x1000017C6: ft_solve (solver.c:45)
==7641==    by 0x100000FBA: main (main.c:49)
==7641== 
==7641== 
==7641== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==7641==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x10408EFB8
==7641==    at 0x100001C31: check_tetrimino (solver.c:134)
==7641==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==7641==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==7641==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==7641==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==7641==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==7641== 
==7641== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7641==     in use at exit: 18,978 bytes in 177 blocks
==7641==   total heap usage: 202 allocs, 25 frees, 25,458 bytes allocated
==7641== 
==7641== 72 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 29 of 47
==7641==    at 0x10009984A: calloc (in /Users/dvan-boc/.brew/Cellar/valgrind/3.14.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==7641==    by 0x1005B2846: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==7641==    by 0x1005C5FE8: objc_object::sidetable_retainCount() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==7641==    by 0x10000903B: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==7641==    by 0x100009255: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==7641==    by 0x10020000A: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==7641==    by 0x1005B2074: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==7641==    by 0x10019368D: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==7641==    by 0x10019363A: libdispatch_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==7641==    by 0x1000A79D5: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==7641==    by 0x100019A1A: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==7641==    by 0x100019C1D: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==7641== 
==7641== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7641==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7641==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7641==      possibly lost: 72 bytes in 3 blocks
==7641==    still reachable: 1,146 bytes in 24 blocks
==7641==         suppressed: 17,760 bytes in 150 blocks
==7641== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==7641== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==7641== 
==7641== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7641== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==7641== ERROR SUMMARY: 21 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 12 from 12)
```

Pic of the debuggger:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXEXH.jpg

Comment: how _grid_ was initialized and me be allocated ? Please give the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) else it is impossible for us to help you, we do not have a magic crystal ball

Comment: probably `grid_size = ft_calc_sqrt(size);` must be `grid_size = ft_calc_sqrt(size) +1;` and `map[grid_size] = NULL;` must be removed because write out of the arrray

Comment: @bruno I've added some extra code and info, basically i auto resolve a set of tetriminoes to the smallest possible solutions, the grid is being generated at the start or whenever we need to grow. we however only crash on the 47.000th recursion, and we do not yet have to re-generate the grid.

Comment: Even if `grid_size` has the right value be sure currently `map[grid_size] = NULL; ` is invalid because you do not allocate enough for it, it is not possible you are on a so small computer a pointer size is 1 ;-). Can you run under _valgrind_ to see your invalid memory accesses ?

Comment: In function `check_all_tetr()` you have `size = ft_strlen(grid[0]); check_ret = check_tetrimino(grid, *curr, ind_y, ind_x);` yet in the called function the same `ft_strlen(grid[0])` on the same data fails. That smells of *undefined behaviour* somewhere, not necessarily there, perhpas revealed in the answers.

Comment: Posting random snippets of code is not helpful. We need a [mcve].

Comment: @bruno, this is the valgrind:
`==7641== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==7641==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x10408EFB8
==7641==    at 0x100001C31: check_tetrimino (solver.c:134)
`

Comment: @Dave is that the *very first* error signaled by _valgrind_ ? Nothing about non initialized value etc ? Give all the _valgrind_ report

Comment: @bruno It's the last
`==7641== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7641==    at 0x100001E2F: ft_strlen (in ./fillit)
==7641==    by 0x10000110D: ft_validator (validator.c:29)
==7641==    by 0x100001339: ft_sort_list (sort_list.c:35)
==7641==    by 0x100000F75: main (main.c:41)
` is the first

Comment: @Dave so it is a consequence of other error(s), again gice *all* the _valgrind_ report

Comment: @bruno added to the OP, the unconditional jumps, are the structs before they are initialized

Comment: @Dave so you use at least a non initialized address, make the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to give us it

Comment: @dave you have to solve the errors from the *first* and progress up to no message at all

Comment: @bruno, aight i'll start at the top then, thx for the effort. also it's a fairly small program, libft isn't required because it's my own made standard library heres my repo: https://github.com/ophionB/fillit

Comment: @Dave it is not possible to compile your code

Comment: Whats the output? @bruno

Comment: @Dave I put in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an invalid memory allocation:

```
map = malloc((grid_size * sizeof(*map)) + 1);
```

It would provide enough space for `grid_size` pointers plus one extra byte, which makes no sense.

```
map[grid_size] = NULL;
```

Here you're trying to store a value one past the last element of the allocated array. The only way this would work is if pointers are only one byte big on your platform (hint: they aren't).

Fix:

```
map = malloc((grid_size + 1) * sizeof(*map));
```

---

The same issue occurs on this line:

```
    map[index] = malloc(grid_size * sizeof(char) + 1);
```

Logically this should be `(grid_size + 1) * sizeof (char)`. However, you're getting bailed out by `sizeof (char)` being `1` by definition, so multiplying by it has no effect.

So even though the code is logically wrong, it produces the right results.

Answer (score 1):

```
(grid_size * sizeof(*map)) + 1
```

is too small – you need

```
(grid_size + 1) * sizeof(*map)
```

Technically, you should do the same with

```
grid_size * sizeof(char) + 1
```

but it works out because `sizeof(char)` is one.

Consider rewriting that one as

```
(grid_size + 1) * sizeof(*map[index])
```

to keep both allocations in the same form.